# The executable was signed with invalid entitlements - 0xe8008016

Tags: ionic-framework, xcode10, code-signing-certificate, build-settings, code-signing-entitlements

I trying to run my app on a device with xcode, it's an ionic app, with xcode 9, 
I had no problem but since I have updated to xcode 10 I keep getting this error message every time:

The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file are invalid, not permitted, or do not match those specified in your provisioning profile.(0xE8008016).

I have tried everything I found online

1.adding capabilities,

2.changing build settings,

3.config.xml.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you are using Xcode 10 you need to change the build system in Workspace Settings to "Legacy Build System"

- File >> Workspace Settings..
- Set build system to "Legacy Build System"

More information can be found here:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/407

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: I dont see a legacy biuild system option

Comment: Time saver. Thank you.

Comment: Update cordova cli version to cordova@9

Comment: you are saving my lifetime

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me , because I had uploaded Distribution Provisioning Profile in Signing debug , once I replaced with Development Provisioning Profile all worked well to me .

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using Legacy Build System you can add directly in info.plist the missing entitlements with the proper key and comment this line in build.xconfig

```
//CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Entitlements-$(CONFIGURATION).plist
```

Example this keys in Entitlements-Debug.plist are no longer valid.

```
<key>com.apple.developer.default-data-protection</key>
<string>NSFileProtectionComplete</string>
```

They can be added in info.plist as

```
<key>DataProtectionClass</key>
<string>NSFileProtectionComplete</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed in version 5.0.0 of cordova-ios, see https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2019/02/09/cordova-ios-release-5.0.0.html

```
cordova platform remove ios
cordova platform add ios@5.0.0
```